# Convert word and excel to html on android

Tags: android, excel, ms-word, apache-poi, apache-tika

I would like to convert word and excel documents to html to show them in the browser in my android app.

I found apache poi library, but it converts practically only text without object like forms, diagrams, wordart etc. Or is it possible and I forgot something?

I found also apache tika, but when I added that library to my project I could'nt compile it because of java heap space error (I have in my eclipse.ini file set Xms768m and Xmx2048m). I tried also to load that library at runtime and tried to use dx tool, but I got outofmemory exception.

What could I do with that or is there any possibility to show office documents in the android app?

Comment: There are some libraries with which you can handle MS Office documents, what do you think about saving them as .pdf and then showing them?

Comment: Saving them as a pdf could be good. Could you give me any examples of such libraries?

Comment: Maybe check the export function from http://www.docx4java.org

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will check that, but I think it does not support old doc and xls format.

Comment: refer to the `Handling legacy binary .doc files` part of their getting started. http://www.docx4java.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/docs/Docx4j_GettingStarted.html

Comment: Yes I've just seen that.

Answer (score 0):

To handle the OOM error while using the dexer:

there is a dx script used during the builds and it sets a default heapsize for the dexer.  The script lives here:

$ANDROID_SDK/build-tools/dx (or dx.bat depending on OS).

There is a section in there that looks like this:

```
# By default, give dx a max heap size of 1 gig. This can be overridden
# by using a "-J" option (see below).
defaultMx="-Xmx1024M"

# The following will extract any initial parameters of the form
# "-J<stuff>" from the command line and pass them to the Java
# invocation (instead of to dx). This makes it possible for you to add
# a command-line parameter such as "-JXmx256M" in your scripts, for
# example. "java" (with no args) and "java -X" give a summary of
# available options.

javaOpts=""
```

Maybe try changing javaOpts to -Xmx2048M  or something like that.